# Regex, continue matching after lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having trouble with lookaround in regex.

Here the problem : I have a big file I want to edit, I want to change a function by another keeping the first parameter but removing the second one.

Let say we have :

```
func1(paramIWantToKeep, paramIDontWant)
```

or

```
func1(func3(paramIWantToKeep), paramIDontWant)
```

I want to change with :

`func2(paramIWantToKeep)` in both case.

so I try using positive lookahead

```
func1\((?=.+), paramIDontWant\)
```

Now, I just try not to select the first parameter (then I'll manage to do the same with the parenthesis).

But it doesn't work, it appears that my regex, after ignoring the positive look ahead (.+) look for `(, paramIDontWant\))` at the same position it was before the look ahead (so the opening parenthesis)

So my question is, how to continue a regex after a matching group, here after (.+).

Thanks.

PS: Sorry for the english and/or the bad construction of my question.

Edit : I use Sublime Text

Comment: It may be helpful to know which language or editor you wish to use for this, as a more comprehensible answer can be given. This mostly seems like a refactoring job, which many decent editors can do for you, though.

Comment: Yes, I use Sublime Text and yes I found a work around with refactoring, but I still want to know how can I continue a regex after a look around, skipping the group I ignored.

Comment: Thats the way lookarounds are working, they ensure at a certain position a condition. You can not "ignore" something in a pattern, either your pattern matches or not. You can match a certain pattern and if you are interested in a certain part, you can extract that part using capturing groups.

Comment: Are "func1" and "func3" known? Ie are they exactly those names?

Comment: So there are no way I can get something like that in regex : 3232stringIDontWant32344 keeping just the numbers ?

Comment: @stema Sorry, I don't see how to upvote a comment or tag a comment as an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Kwelity, no problem, I don't think that my comment is a complete answer (I haven't had the time to write a good one, but I think Kendall did the job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that a regex will always match a consecutive string. There will never be gaps.

Therefore, if you want to replace `123abc456` with `abc`, you can't simply match `123456` and remove it.

Instead, you can use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). This will allow you to remember a section of the regex for later.

For example, to replace `123abc456` with `abc`, you could replace this regex:

```
\d+([a-z]+)\d+
```

with this string:

```
$1
```

What that does is actually replaces the match with the contents of the first capturing group. In this case, the capturing group was `([a-z]+)`, which matches `abc`. Thus, the entire match is replaced with just `abc`.

---

An example you may find more useful:

Given:

```
func1(foo, bar)
```

replacing this regex:

```
\w+\((\w+),\s*\w+\)
```

with this string:

```
func2($1)
```

results in:

```
func2(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```python
import re
t = "func1(paramKeep,paramLose)"
t1 = "func1(paramKeep,((paramLose(dog,cat))))"
t2 = "func1(func3(paramKeep),paramDont)"
t3 = "func1(func3(paramKeep),paramDont,((i)),don't,want,these)"

reg = r'(\w+\(.*?(?=,))(,.*)(\))'

keep,lose,end = re.match(reg,t).groups()
print(keep+end)

keep,lose,end = re.match(reg,t1).groups()
print(keep+end)

keep,lose,end = re.match(reg,t2).groups()
print(keep+end)

keep,lose,end = re.match(reg,t3).groups()
print(keep+end)
```

Produces

```python
>>> 
func1(paramKeep)
func1(paramKeep)
func1(func3(paramKeep))
func1(func3(paramKeep))
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed I manage to do this using group replacing within my text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Apply these two regexp in this order

```
s/(func1)([^,]*)(, )?(paramIDontWant)(.)/func2$2$5/;
s/(func2\()(func3\()(paramIWantToKeep).*/$1$3)/;
```

These cope with the two examples you gave.  I guess that the real world code you are editing is slightly more complicated but the general idea of applying a series of regexps might be helpful

Comment: Thank you, I first wanted to do this in one regex, but it appears that I can't do to the the concept of look around, I'll be using grouping or more than one regex then.